RegEx in SUMO Logic: How can I Parse with nested quotes?
I'm still very new to Sumo and less experienced with RegEx. I'm trying to extract the following number from the logs. I've found success in the past since usually our logs that I need are XML formatted, but this is the first time I've had to work with nested quotes and (what seems to be) unnamed capture groups.
From
"ConfirmationNumber":"9409362761561486406859"

I need
9409362761561486406859

with no quotes.
and there will be a varying amount of these in the logs I'll be parsing. It could range from 1 to 500, or even more depending on the project, but higher numbers will not be the norm.
I'm hoping someone might have some insight on how I can format the parse section. This is what I had copied from my previous attempts at parsing XML data, which obviously would never have worked.
| extract "<ConfirmationNumber>(?<ConfirmationNumber>.*?)?<," multi nodrop

Thank you in advance!

You need to specify four double quotes, as that is the number of quotes in the format you expect, and as there is no <, following what you want to match, those symbols should not be in your regex (maybe a left-over from your previous XML case?).
That results in this:
| extract "<ConfirmationNumber>":"(?<ConfirmationNumber>.*?)" multi nodrop


Hi @trincot So yes, that [<,] was left over from my XML case. I tried what you had here (a copy and paste into my log search), but was getting this error: No capture group found in regex, regex="". An example of a valid "extract" usage is [extract "From: (?.) To: (?.)"] (sorry, I'm still super inexperienced with this... I'm not totally positive what it's missing)

After some testing I was able to successfully get this to work:
| parse regex "\"ConfirmationNumber\":\"(?<ConfirmationNumber>[0-9]*)\"" multi nodrop

